# Windows Batch: Build string from lines in text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple text file containing one file name per file. I want to merge all of these files. My plan for this was to read the text file, build a string like "filename1+file2+f3" and then use that as a parameter to copy /b.

However, I am having trouble reading the file correctly.

Here is what I have right now:

```
SET x=
FOR /F %%G IN (merge.txt) DO SET x=%x%+%%G
ECHO %x%
```

However, the "recursion" here does not seem to work properly and %x% just gets set to "+fl", where fl is the last filename in the file.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct, but you are just missing the delayed expansion usage.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "x="
FOR /F %%G IN (merge.txt) DO SET x=!x!+%%G
ECHO %x%

REM Trim the leading +
SET x=%x:~1,999%
ECHO %x%    

ENDLOCAL
```

Without the delayed expansion, `%x%` is *only* evaluated when the `FOR` loop starts, so it would be blank for each iteration. By enabling delayed expansion, `!x!` (the notation for this) is evaluated on each iteration so it will build the compound string you are looking for.